# Back-end access and secret keys required?

Tags: amazon-s3, docker, amazon-iam, docker-registry

Are Docker Registry S3 back-end access and secret keys required? I don't understand why.

I use an IAM role and can't get access and secret keys from that. Before I didn't have to provide access and secret key to s3 settings in docker registry and it worked automatically since the IAM role granted the server access to the s3 resources. Now the keys are required in the YAML setting (I use docker compose to spin up registry) and it won't start without them.

Is there some way to get around this without having to add an IAM user?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. All I did was take out the following field and let the docker registry do it's magic (picking up access/secret key from the IAM role I assume)

Delete these 2 entries from docker-compose.yml:

```
REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY: xxx
REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY: xxx
```